# Ford F150 2009 will not start!! (Has power)

Tags: ford, no-crank-no-start, electronic-control-module, anti-theft

Last update: we got our truck back and it was that someone who had checked about the lights "accidently" changed fuses out of place and some went missing. It works now.

Update 2: We gave up and send it to Ford dealer services. We have not heard from them in 2 days :(

Update 1: Lights are working now - it was a wire by the fuse box on the passenger side that was not connected all the way (we clicked it in now) but now we have to figure out how to make the truck start.

**Thank you guys for replying back**

Sorry for this long story. My husband's truck was hit on passenger side. The door was replaced by another door and everything worked well until he saw tail lights were not coming on when braking. Neither were the turning signals. We checked fuses, we changed bulbs, still not working (left and rights sides) top light works fine. So we went to YT and saw a lot of videos we ended up resetting the truck by unplugging the battery and leaving it for a few minutes. When we connected back the anti-theft light came up it has power but will not crank or start. We tried again with YT videos how to try to turn it on or get the anti theft light off but nothing seems to work.

Comment: It could be an [Inertia Switch](https://www.google.com/search?q=inertia+switch), thrown when the accident happened.  If you can find the switch you can reset it; [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AUWzaFsedzI&ab_channel=LehewTech) might be appropriate for your F150

Comment: @gowenfawr - That was my initial thought until the OP explained it had been running after the accident up until they unplugged the battery. The problem lies in the security system for the truck. Not sure how to fix it, but the security light is the give away in my head.

Comment: @gowenfawr thanks but i think ours doesn't have that its a 2009 f150

Answer (score 2):

Last update: we got our truck back and it was that someone who had checked about the lights "accidently" changed fuses out of place and some went missing. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Top Answer given here; https://www.vehiclehistory.com/questions/how-do-i-perform-the-2009-ford-f150-anti-theft-reset-205448. Your key has an embedded chip (rfid?) programmed to your F150 security system. Your owner's manual should have info otherwise F150 forums are your best sources of info.  This may be a security issue preventing startup, battery or starter problem.